# Retofit2 acessando api GET

Tags: java, android, retrofit

eu estou utilizando o retrofit2 para acessar uma API... Acontece que eu não consigo obter os dados dessa API.

[Link para API utilizada](https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/)

Eu consegui fazer o meu código funcionar com essa API: ([Essa](https://www.udacity.com/public-api/v0/courses)), mas quando eu refaço o código para utilizar a anterior, eu recebo o erro de nullPointer na ActivityMain na linha do primeiro foreach que exibe os resultados.

Código:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UdacityService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    UdacityService service = retrofit.create(UdacityService.class);
    Call<CharacterCatalog> requestCatalog = service.listCatalog();

    requestCatalog.enqueue(new Callback<CharacterCatalog>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CharacterCatalog> call, Response<CharacterCatalog> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("ERRO", "Erro no servidor (" + response.code() + ")");
            }
            else {
                CharacterCatalog catalog = response.body();
                for (Result c : catalog.results){
                    Log.i("RESULT", String.format("id; %s, name: %s\n",c.id, c.name));

                    for (Origin o : c.origins){
                        Log.i("RESULT", String.format("nome; %s, url: %s\n",o.name, o.url));
                    }
                    Log.i("RESULT", "/////////////////////////////////////////");
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CharacterCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERRO", "Verifique a conexão com a internet (" + t.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    });
}}
```

Interface retofit:

```
public interface ApiService {
public static final  String BASE_URL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/";

@GET("character")
Call<CharacterCatalog> listCatalog();
}
```

Lista com os resultados:

```
public class CharacterCatalog {
public List<Result> results;
}
```

Class Result

```
public class Result {
public String id;
public String name;
public String status;
public String species;
public String gender;

public List<Origin> origins;
}
```

Class Origin:

```
public class Result {
public String id;
public String name;
public String status;
public String species;
public String gender;

public List<Origin> origins;
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar com esse erro?

Comment: Sai algum erro no logcat?

Comment: Aparece, mas acho que não está relacionado com o app, fica dando erro de audio do emulador..

Comment: Aparentemente a api não retorna um array `origins` e sim um objeto `origin` no character. O nullpointer é nessa variável?

Comment: Era isso mesmo!! tirei o list e deixei para receber só o objeto e deu certo! obrigado ai.